# Jquery: .click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link on my php file which when has an event listener attached to it and clicks another link on the same page.

```
 <p>Upload the image you want on your cake:<a href="#" id="upload-button" class="button">Upload</a> </p>

<a href="#openModal" id="upload-link"></a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <?php require 'image-upload.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
        $('#upload-button').on('click', function () {//This works fine
            $('#upload-link')[0].click(); //This doesn't work.
        });`

    </script>
```

Now click event should click the **upload-link** and a modal should pop.However, nothing happens.What could be the reason and the solution?

Comment: Have you defined a click event on the `<a href="#openModal" id="upload-link"></a>` button?

Comment: $('#upload-link').click(); equals $('#upload-link').on("click", function) which listens on the click event instead of clicks itself;

Comment: `$('#upload-link').trigger("click");` you should handle trigger this way

Comment: Isn't click event itself an event and the `.on('click')` Does the same ?

Comment: You'd better read the jQuery documentation so you can have a better understanding.

Comment: okay i get that .So how do i make it work?

Comment: Where is your code that should open modal?

Answer (score 1):

Add jQuery to your HTML by putting

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before your custom script.

Besides as it is now, your div will always show up. you should set up a dynamic way to hide/show it.
You can use jQuery hide() and show() methods on your elements like

```
$("#close").click(function(e){
    $("#openModal").hide();
});
```

also your identifiers syntax should always be the same . All camelCase or all i-dont-know-how-this-case-is-called .

Comment: Look at my edit. Also, your code displays succesfully if you replace your php by some HTML.

Comment: .php files doesn't contains some html code.It should n't be a issue,right?

Comment: Well it should not but it can help debugging if you know your PHP doesn't get in the way. 
As i said, no modal will pop because you declare your div and don't hide or show it: it's just a blank div with some php inside, without any style or so. You can't expect much of it.
BTW if you don't show all your code nobody will & can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know why it didn't work previously but when i  made some changes to the upload button link.Everything worked and the modal pops up just fine.

```
<p>Upload the image you want on your cake:<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="upload-button" class="button">Upload</a> </p>
```

I Just changed the href from `#` to `javascript: void(0)` and everything just worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me. But, (FYI), id's should not contain hyphens.

**NOTE**: I am only using an inline HTML event handler on #openModal to show that its click event is being triggered, but you haven't added any actions to that link, so otherwise it would do nothing. DO NOT USE INLINE HTML EVENT HANDLERS IN PRACTICE.

```js
$(function(){

        $('#uploadButton').on('click', function () {
           alert("Upload Button has been clicked");
            $('#uploadLink').trigger("click");
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Upload the image you want on your cake:<a href="#" id="uploadButton" class="button">Upload</a> </p>

<a href="#openModal" id="uploadLink" onclick="alert('Open Modal has been clicked!')">I am the Open Modal link</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">I am the Close link</a>
        <?php require 'image-upload.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't see what your .php file produces and so, that's as far as I can test.  Can you post the resulting code from the .php?

Comment: That just echoes some content.Nothing more than that.

Comment: @TanviMalhotra The reason that the second click doesn't work is because you have it clicking a hyperlink that is not set up to go anywhere or do anything.

Comment: what should i do then ?in order to open up the modal?

Comment: And that hyperlink does open up when i click directly on that instead of doing this procedure

Comment: @TanviMalhotra Then there is more code you aren't showing because `<a href="#openModal" id="uploadLink"></a>` doesn't link to anything except an element who's id is `#openModal`. This would normally cause only a scroll to that element.  Are you using Bootstrap? There's something you've left out.

Comment: @TanviMalhotra The openModal div is already visible when the page loads, so a click of the link would just scroll to it, but you say it "opens up" for you when you click the link directly, so can you explain what "opens up" means?

Comment: by open up i mean to say is that Pops up

Comment: @TanviMalhotra Then you have more code that you aren't showing us. Bootstrap?  I've updated my code with a temporary action for the link to perform to show you that my code, does in fact trigger the click event.

Comment: I anwered my own question .I still don't get the reason behind this bizzare reaction.Wanna Explain?

Comment: It's not a bizarre reaction as several of us have said. Your (and my) code does trigger the click of the hyperlink, but the hyperlink you've shown `<a href="#openModal" id="upload-link"></a>` has no `href` that would take you anywhere, except to scroll that part of the page into view. If something else is happening for you, it's because you have more code than you are telling us and showing us because that code alone wouldn't "open a modal dialog". Bootstrap perhaps?